# Error: Cannot read property 'function' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling a method inside another method, and when I do it it does not find the method I am calling, I do not understand how to do so that when calling the function it knows that it is outside the method.

```
export default class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null,
            info: {}
        }
        this.ConsumirGraph = this.ConsumirGraph.bind(this)
        
    }
ConsumirGraph = (token, send) => {
        var info = new Object();
            this.state.info = info
        $.ajax({
            url: send,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                debugger;
                if (data["@odata.context"] === "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(department)/$entity") {
                    info.obj = data;
                    console.log(info)
                } else if (data["@odata.context"] === "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects/$entity") {
                    info.jefe = data;
                    console.log(info)
                } else {
                    info.user = data;
                    console.log(info)
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                debugger;
                console.log(error);
            }
    
        });
    }

    graphi() {
        authContext.acquireToken(adalConfig.endpoints.graphApiUri, function(error, token) {
            if (error) {
                if (adalConfig.popUp) {
                    authContext.acquireTokenPopup(adalConfig.endpoints.graphApiUri, null, null, function(errorDesc, token, error) {});
                    console.log("ADAL error occurred: " + error);
                    return;
                } else {
                    authContext.acquireTokenRedirect(adalConfig.endpoints.graphApiUri, null, null);
                }
            } else {
                console.log('va bien de momentp')
                var headers = new Headers();
                var bearer = "Bearer " + token;
                headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
                var options = {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: headers
                };
                var graphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
                let jefe = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/manager";
                let getMemberGroups = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=department";
                fetch(graphEndpoint, options)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.ConsumirGraph(token, getMemberGroups);
                    this.ConsumirGraph(token, jefe);
                    this.ConsumirGraph(token, graphEndpoint)
                    
                })
            }
        });    
    }
```

Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'ConsumirGraph' of undefined

Comment: What's the line of the error?

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of `this.ConsumirGraph` to `this.ConsumirGraph.bind(this)` inside the constructor is not needed, you should simply put `this.ConsumirGraph.bind(this)` itself in the constructor.

So the constructor should look like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null,
            info: {}
        }
        this.ConsumirGraph.bind(this)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

every function has a `this` pointer. it's mean `authContext.acquireToken` second argument need to bind with class and gets the class `this` pointer.
but you can simply convert `authContext.acquireToken` second argument to arrow function to make it work.